# Two android applications were installed on the phone when click run with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

After the run button clicked using eclipse, two same icons were added on the phone. But only one of them is the real application, the other one will be force closed immediately once opened. And if I uninstall one of the applications, the other one will also be removed.

What happened with my eclipse and applications?

Comment: Show your manifest.xml here

Comment: Are you giving launcher filter in two activities in your manifest.xml?

Comment: Thank U Pr38y. It is caused by the two activities with launcher filter!